# django JSONField contains greater than

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-jsonfield

I have the model `Item` with JSON field

```
metadata = JSONField(null=True)
```

sample content:
`[{"value": 50, name: "other"}, {"value": 60, name: "other2"}]`

How can I query all rows where exists a "value" larger than 50?

I tried

```
Item.objects.filter(metadata__contains__value__gt=50)
```

I've managed to query an exact value with

```
Item.objects.filter(metadata__contains=[{"value": 50}])
```

Comment: Does your metadata field contain only one item? (that is, will be the **`len(metadata)`** is 1 always?

Comment: @JPG No, it does contains multiple items.

Comment: If so, it's not possible (AFAIK)

Comment: Any way to fix the json schema so it will be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Django, as of version 4.1, doesn't have this built-in. Fortunately, in PostgreSQL you can achieve this (refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html), and Django allows you to write custom SQL and Lookups.

In PostgreSQL, you can use the following in the WERE clause (both lines are equivalent):

```
jsonb_path_exists(metadata, '$[*] ? (@.value > 50)')
jsonb_path_exists(metadata, '$[*] ? (@.value > $val)', '{"val": 50}')
```

One way to achieve this in Django is to use `RawSQL`, however passing parametres other than numbers is tricky, as they will be surrounded in quotes and break it. Also, we can make it reusable by implementing a lookup.

Here is a simplified version of how you could achieve this with a custom lookup. Explanation for some design choices is in the form of comments.

```py
class JSONBPath(RawSQL):
    """Wrapper for a JSONB path."""
    def __init__(self, sql, params: dict | list | None = None):
        # `params` must be a JSON serializable instance that will be
        # passed as the third parameter of `jsonb_path_exists`
        # We will not use `params` in this class, more reasons below
        if params is not None:
            params = Value(params, output_field=JSONField())
        super().__init__(sql, params)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        # We are quoting the placeholder and there could be a risk of
        # SQL injection if passing the parameters here. Furthermore
        # if passing strings, they will be wrapped in single quotes and
        # you will get a syntax error. Hence we make the params an empty
        # tuple and let `JSONBPathExists` handle the params.
        return "('%s')" % self.sql, tuple()

class JSONBPathExists(Lookup):
    lookup_name = "path_exists"

    def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, JSONBPath):
            # Trick to handle the json parameters, as we cannot pass
            # more parameters to the lookup, and to avoid the issues 
            # mentioned above
            self.jsonb_vars: Value | None = rhs.params
        else:
            self.jsonb_vars = None
        super().__init__(lhs, rhs)

    def process_jsonb_vars(self, compiler, connection):
        """
        Converts and cleans json_vars to SQL and params,
        so that it is safe.
        """
        if self.jsonb_vars is None:
            return "", ()
        return self.jsonb_vars.as_sql(compiler, connection)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        jsonb_vars, jsonb_vars_params = self.process_jsonb_vars(compiler, connection)
        if jsonb_vars:
            params = tuple(lhs_params) + tuple(rhs_params) + tuple(jsonb_vars_params)
            return "jsonb_path_exists(%s, %s, %s)" % (lhs, rhs, jsonb_vars), params
        else:
            params = tuple(lhs_params) + tuple(rhs_params)
            return "jsonb_path_exists(%s, %s)" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

Note that we are passing any extra parameters provided by the user as a JSON value, to prevent the issues with strings being wrapped in single quotes and SQL injection vulnerability.

You can register the lookup for `JSONField` and then perform your query as follows:

```py
Item.objects.filter(metadata__path_exists=JSONBPath("$[*] ? (@.value > $val)", {"val": 50}))
```

Or without registering the lookup:

```py
Item.objects.filter(JSONBPathExists(F("metadata"), JSONBPath("$[*] ? (@.value > $val)", {"val": 50})))
```

Answer (score 0):

To query based on a given dictionary key, simply use that key as the lookup name.
For example:

`Item.objects.filter(metadata__value__gte=50)`

Comment: But here the dictionary key is inside the array, what operator "moves" into the array? Since this does not work for me